# What are "best practices" for wp-config.php

Tags: customization, wp-config

Just started reading *Professional WordPress®: Design and Development*

I'm reading the section on **"Advanced wp-config Options"**.

I see many options which I think are pretty cool/useful, but before I ***go crazy*** using "Advanced wp-config Options" I thought I'd **inquire about "Best Practices"** from the veterans in this area.

I'm still a noob and a little knowledge is a *"dangerous thing"* :-}

For example book states:

> To set your WordPress address and blog address, use the following two
>   options:
>
> define('WP_SITEURL', ‘http://example.com/wordpress');
>
> define('WP_HOME', ‘http://example.com/wordpress');
>
> The WP_SITEURL option allows you to temporarily change the WordPress
>   site URL....

I read this and think, **best use** is for taking site offline temporarily (for maintentance, etc.). Otherwise, why use this?

But there are some options which read like they **SHOULD** be used (at least as a best practice). So I thought I would ask how the vets approach these config options (or for general advice to noobs). I know what these options (below) do, question is should I (do you) use them and  why/not?

- WP_POST_REVISIONS
- AUTOSAVE_INTERVAL
- WP_DEBUG SAVEQUERIES
- WP_MEMORY_LIMIT
- FTP_USER
- FTP_PASS
- FTP_HOST
- WP_CACHE
- FORCE_SSL_LOGIN
- FORCE_SSL_ADMIN

Thanks In Advance!

sleeper

Comment: Have you [read what all of them do](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php)? Most of these are obvious if you understand what they do and have a need for them with your particular server and use case.

Comment: @Milo Yup. There all in the book I'm reading and (of course), the CODEX. Again, was just "checking" for caveats, recommendations, etc. regarding config.php advanced options. thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no best practices: You just do what you need for your web site. These needs are different for each site, so the default is good enough for most sites.

If you read the [wp-config](/questions/tagged/wp-config) questions you’ll find some tricks and information. But I wouldn’t recommend anything for *every* site, not even for most sites.

Comment: Understood. I guess I was wondering about best practices like (for example) do you guys routinely increase AUTOSAVE_INTERVAL to save space. stuff like that. But I see your point about the variables of each site. Thanks for all replies.